# Get data from dynamoDB in lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

the function successful but the output empty. Any code, I m missing??

[image]

Comment: What does you handler return?

Comment: I not ss the code inside, let me ss again

Comment: What is `ApiResponse`?

Comment: It is a imoport libaray "from api_response import ApiResponse"

Comment: Where's the link to this library? Is it open-source?